# ConvexHullMesh make a hollow object

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a very specific and weird question concerning ConvexHullMesh. I have e.g. two lists of points which I make a convex hull. By combining these two convexhulls I get inside faces. My goal is however to obtain an object which is hollow. Does anybody know how this is done in Mathematica?

```
list1 = {{11.0074, -46.2901, 136.79}, {11.1255, -46.4357, 
  136.79}, {11.3436, -46.3722, 136.79}, {11.0074, -46.2901, 
  136.89}, {11.1255, -46.4357, 136.89}, {11.3436, -46.3722, 136.89}}

list2 = {{11.0074, -46.2901, 136.79}, {11.3436, -46.3722, 
  136.79}, {10.9323, -46.1975, 136.79}, {11.0074, -46.2901, 
  136.89}, {11.3436, -46.3722, 136.89}, {10.9323, -46.1975, 136.89}}

ch1 = ConvexHullMesh[list1];
ch2 = ConvexHullMesh[list2];
RegionPlot3D[{ch1, ch2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
 Background -> Black, Boxed -> False]
```

Im pretty sure someone will suggest to write list1 and list2 as one list and the problem is solved. But as I said my case is very specific and I have to consider two separate lists.

Comment: Provide an example set of points and code that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
p1 = RandomPoint[Ball[], 100];
p2 = RandomPoint[Ball[{1, 0, 0}], 100];

vr = RegionUnion[
   ConvexHullMesh[p1],
   ConvexHullMesh[p2]
]
```

Now `vr` is a solid region. `ar = RegionBoundary[vr]` is a surface region, i.e. hollow.

```
RegionDimension /@ {vr, ar}
(* {3, 2} *)
```

Both of them will *look* hollow when plotted with `RegionPlot3D`.